# Verilog always block execution during startup

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I have an always block in verilog as shown below. All the input signals inside always block are not stable until startup time say 50ns. I don't want to execute the always block until start up time is reached. What is the best to achieve this functionality? Thanks.

```
always begin
 //functional code
 #10
end
```

Comment: Is for synthesizable code? If yes, you'll need another *powerup" signal

Comment: No this is just a behavioral model for an analog circuit. No synthesis needed.

Comment: why is #10 there? looks like it is significant for you. is this always block supposed to be with no sensitivity list?

Comment: well I added delay as no sensitivity list is specified but I can add sensitivity list and remove the delay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an `initial` block

```
initial #50ns forever begin /* functional code */ #10; end
```

or for combinational logic, use

```
initial #50ns forever @* begin /* functional code */ end
```

Comment: Thanks Dave this will work. But is there a way to achieve this using always block?

Comment: Yes, but much more difficult. You would have to set a flag for the first time in the always block to wait for 50ns, the check the flag every time through the loop.